# Trouble with Isometric Graphic alignment

Tags: python, pygame, isometric

I am having problems with my system aligning on the top left -> bottom right axis.

Here is a picture.
[image: Photo of problem]

I'm using 3.11.2 version of python.

Here is my code

```
import pygame
import sys
import numpy as np

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

# Constants for tile size and screen dimensions
TILE_SIZE = 128
SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT = 1200, 1220

# Calculate the number of tiles that fit on the screen
num_horizontal_tiles = SCREEN_WIDTH // TILE_SIZE * 2
num_vertical_tiles = SCREEN_HEIGHT // TILE_SIZE * 2

# Define colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

# Create the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Isometric Tile Demo")

# Define an isometric tileset (PNG images)
tile_width = TILE_SIZE
tile_height = TILE_SIZE

# Function to load and draw isometric tiles
def draw_isometric_tile(x, y, image_path):
    iso_x = x - y // 2
    iso_y = (x + y) // 4 + TILE_SIZE // 4  # Adjust the Y position
    tile_image = pygame.image.load(image_path)
    tile_image = pygame.transform.scale(tile_image, (tile_width, tile_height))
    screen.blit(tile_image, (iso_x, iso_y))

# Terrain generation
terrain = np.random.choice(['grass', 'dirt', 'sand', 'water'], size=(num_horizontal_tiles, num_vertical_tiles), p=[0.6, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1])

# Define rules for terrain generation
terrain_rules = {
    'grass': ['dirt'],
    'dirt': ['grass', 'sand'],
    'sand': ['dirt', 'water'],
    'water': ['sand']
}

# Perform cellular automaton steps
for _ in range(5):  # You can adjust the number of iterations as needed
    new_terrain = terrain.copy()
    for x in range(num_horizontal_tiles):
        for y in range(num_vertical_tiles):
            current_terrain = terrain[x, y]
            neighboring_terrains = [terrain[i, j] for i in range(x - 1, x + 2) for j in range(y - 1, y + 2)
                                    if 0 <= i < num_horizontal_tiles and 0 <= j < num_vertical_tiles]
            new_terrain[x, y] = np.random.choice(terrain_rules[current_terrain])

    terrain = new_terrain

# Define the mapping of terrain types to image paths
terrain_images = {
    'grass': "C:/Users/seth/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/terrain_images/Isometric Grass tile 2.png",
    'dirt': "C:/Users/seth/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/terrain_images/Isometric Dirt tile.png",
    'sand': "C:/Users/seth/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/terrain_images/isometric Sand tile.png",
    'water': "C:/Users/seth/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/terrain_images/Isometric Water tile.png"
}

# Main game loop
running = True

# Initial camera position
camera_x, camera_y = 0, 0

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # Handle camera movement
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        camera_x -= 5
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        camera_x += 5
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        camera_y -= 5
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        camera_y += 5

    # Clear the screen
    screen.fill(WHITE)

    # Draw isometric tiles based on camera position
    for x in range(num_horizontal_tiles):
        for y in range(num_vertical_tiles):
            tile_type = terrain[x, y]  # Get terrain type at this position
            image_path = terrain_images.get(tile_type, "")  # Get image path based on terrain type
            if image_path:
                draw_isometric_tile((x - camera_x) * tile_width + SCREEN_WIDTH // 2,
                                    (y - camera_y) * tile_height + SCREEN_HEIGHT // 2, image_path)

    pygame.display.flip()

# Quit Pygame
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't have the graphic you used, but I found this to try:

[sample tile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VcIz.png)

then, remember to divide by two (google : isometric tiles size in games)

> tile_height = TILE_SIZE // 2

and next step ( in my opinion you just missed that you need a bracket here ):

> iso_x = (x - y) // 2

and also:

> (y - camera_y) * tile_height * 2 + SCREEN_HEIGHT // 2, image_path)

works fine for me:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcbUe.png)